# jQuery Syntax error, unrecognized expression using Angular, Angular UI-Router and Materialize Together

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-ui-router, materialize, angular2-materialize

I'm using several libraries with this project. The one that is complaining is jQuery. I'm not sure that jQuery is actually the culprit here. I've tried several different methods to get the desired result and I've ended up with a solution that results in the fewest errors and still functions correctly. OK, so I'm using jQuery, Materialize, Angular, Angular UI-Router and Angular Materialize. I have several routes defined and also nested views. So, on to the code:

```
<ul tabs>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#/one" ui-sref="one" ui-sref-active="active">One</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#/two" ui-sref="two" ui-sref-active="active">Two</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#/three" ui-sref="three" ui-sref-active="active">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, this method, by combining `href="#/one"` with `ui-sref="one"` on the anchor element functions correctly, but still produces an error on the initial app load. `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/one`.

Just about all search results for this error have something to do with the format of strings and quotes. This leads me to believe that it has something to do with one of the libraries. Most likely Materialize or UI-Router. Maybe both together.

Here is a Fiddle that reproduces the problem – https://jsfiddle.net/whatisthebigpicture/9uudedvx/ – the scripts are loaded in HTML because the external scripts panel wasn't working correctly. It was a challenge to reproduce the same problem on JSFiddle, but I'm confident that if it can be solved in the Fiddle then I can apply it to my app.

Does anyone have experience using these libraries together? Is there something I can do to get rid of the error or is it up to the library devs?

Comment: I haven't used that recently, but it sure as hell seems weird for it to require you including jquery and materialize, AND an angular materialize component. The documentation doesn't even suggest doing that. https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize

Comment: Please stop adding tags to your title, they don't belong.

Comment: My original title wasn't allowed and then I thought about it and adding the library names to the title is very relevant.

Comment: It isn't relevant, as you've already added them with tags. The expression that wasn't recognized however IS relevant, and isn't included...

Comment: jQuery is required by Matarialize. Angular Materialize provides directives for Materialize and Angular to work together.

Comment: Angular Materialize with use JQLite if jquery isn't included, it isn't required. The documentation does not say angular materialize requires materialize.

Comment: I was wrong, the getting started sample DOES include both, but in a slightly different order. http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#getting-started

Comment: It includes a number of directives, which makes sure that the components in materialize.js, which are mainly initialized on document ready, are handled by Angular in the right way.

So it is not a complete rewrite of Materialize. And it therefore depends on jQuery, because Materialize depends on jQuery. – http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#getting-started

Comment: The expression that wasn't recognized could be anything, it's the route and isn't relevant. Using the libraries together, however, is relevant.

Comment: Please do not downvote my question. There are very good reasons for every aspect of it.

Comment: html5 mode seems to sidestep it. Suggest debugging further with non-minified files.

Comment: From the looks of it, Materialize is taking the hash of the anchor tag and passing it to $(), which will of course throw an error because `/` isn't valid in an id selector.

Comment: I updated the Fiddle to not use minified versions, but still get the same error with no additional information. What do you mean by HTML5 mode sidesteps it?

Comment: In other words, materialize tabs requires working with the url, and so does ui-router. they don't appear to be compatible unless one or the other simply doesn't touch the hash.

Comment: Using minified versions implies following up with digging through the source code for more information. The error message shouldn't change.

Comment: Oh, HTML5 mode with Angular UI-Router. That actually won't work in my app because it's not running on Apache.

Comment: Can you make material tabs not use the hash? doesn't appear to support that, so you might just be out of luck.

Comment: I have to have the hash because my app isn't running on a server so I can't do any URL rewriting.

Comment: I don't think you're reading my comments thoroughly. my last comment was asking about material tabs' hash which has nothing to do with running on a server, not ui-router.

Comment: I'm reading your comments perfectly fine. The hash has everything to do with running it on a server. If I don't have a hash then the browser is going to be looking in a location that doesn't exist unless you have something like Apache telling it where to look.

Comment: Right, but angular material tabs, like most other tab systems, use the hash to allow deep linking, and don't expect the server to do anything with it. It's not used for navigating to different pages, instead it's used for navigating to different tabs. Because of this, it cannot be used with ui-router in non-html5 mode. (unless you wanted to dig in and modify the source to remove said functionality)

Comment: I've contacted one of the other developers to see if I can get some form of URL rewriting. Thanks for the tip on HTML5 mode, it's what I would prefer anyway. So which library do you think is at fault here? Is it jQuery for not allowing the slash after the hash? Or is it UI-Router and Angular for using that scheme?

Comment: It's a direct conflict between the materialize tabs widget and ui-router, they're fighting for control of the url hash. Not an angular or jquery problem.

Comment: They should probably be using what Angular originally used. I think they called it a hash bang #! That totally makes sense now.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error by commenting out 3 lines in materialize.js. Version 0.97.7. Line 1272, 1296, and 1323. It doesn't appear to have any effect on my app other than removing the error. Thanks @KevinB for helping me zero in on Materialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-href="#/one"` instead of plain old `href="#/one"`. Working Fiddle – https://jsfiddle.net/whatisthebigpicture/rj08fosn/

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2848